# Algorithm to Compute square of a directed graph(represented in form of an adjacency list)

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I am working on constructing an algorithm to compute G^2 of a directed graph that is a form of an adjacency list, where G^2 = (V,E'), where E' is defined as (u,v)∈E′ if there is a path of length 2 between u and v in G. I understand the question very well and have found an algorithm which I assume is correct, however the runtime of my algorithm is O(VE^2) where V is the number of vertices and E is the number of Edges of the graph. I was wondering how I could do this in O(VE) time in order to make it more efficient?

Here is the algorithm, I came up with:

for vertex in Vertices
 for neighbor in Neighbors
   for n in Neighbors
     if(n!=neighbor)
       then-> if(n.value==neighbor)
         add this to a new adjacency list
         break; // this means we have found a path of size 2 between vertex           and neighbor
       continue otherwise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem can be solved in time **O(VE)** using `BFS`(breadth first search). The thing about `BFS`, is that it traverses the graph `level by level`. Meaning that first it traverses all the vertices at a `distance of 1` from the `source vertex`. Then it traverses all the vertices at a `distance of 2` from the `source vertex` and so on. So we can take advantage of this fact and terminate our `BFS`, when we have reached vertices at a `distance of 2`.

Following is the pseudocode:

```
For each vertex v in V
{
 Do a BFS with v as source vertex
 {
  For all vertices u at distance of 2 from v
  add u to adjacency list of v 
  and terminate BFS
 }
}
```

Since `BFS` takes time **O(V + E)** and we invoke this for every vertex, so total time is **O(V(V + E))** = **O(V^2 + VE)** = **O(VE)** .Just remember to start with fresh data structures for every `BFS` traversal.